# CMake set_property() doesn't seem to work for source file

Tags: cmake

I tried to add some compile definitions to some source files, so I make configuration like this:

```
set_property(
    SOURCE main.cpp
    APPEND
    PROPERTY
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "VERSION=3"
)
```

and I use `make VERBOSE=1` to check the configuration, but there doesn't exist `-DVERSION=3` or similar things while compiling the `main.cpp.o`.
Then I made another try：

```
set_property(
    DIRECTORY
    APPEND
    PROPERTY
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "VERSION=3"
)
```

then I get `-DVERSION=3`. Why does `set_property()` not work for `SOURCE`? I have tried this in CMake 2.8.12 and CMake 3.10 with GNU Makefile generator.

Comment: Oh, I get it. When choosing `SOURCE`, an absolute path is needed. In above case, main.cpp should replaced by its absolute path. On the other hand, `DIRECTORY` will use the current path by default. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `set_property(SOURCE ...)` signature, a source file with a relative path will be interpreted as relative to the *current CMakeLists.txt file*. Thus, your file `main.cpp` **must** be in the same directory as the current CMakeLists.txt file when specifying a relative path. It is always safest (in order to avoid issues such as yours) to use absolute paths whenever possible:

```
set_property(
    SOURCE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/main.cpp
    APPEND
    PROPERTY
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "VERSION=3"
)
```

An additional requirement of the `set_property(SOURCE ...)` command is the following (from the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html)):

> `SOURCE`
>
> Scope may name zero or more source files. **Note that source file properties are visible only to targets added in the same directory (`CMakeLists.txt`)**.

So, the CMake target using the source file *must* be defined in the same CMakeLists.txt file that calls `set_property()` on the source file.